# Create list of csv files, open one, loop through each row, then open the next and loop through each row?

Tags: r

I have multiple csv files with the same columns but a different number of rows. 
 For each csv column, I want to get the name of the csv file, open it, get the name of the file, then split one column into two based on the "-" character.  I have no problem with this loop:

```
l <- list.files(".", full.names = TRUE)
for(i in length(l)){
    #Get the sample name form the name of the sheet
nm <- gsub("C:/Users/jmartin/Documents/20181130_Butte_Dust/tracking_sheets/","",l[[i]])
nm <- gsub(".csv","",nm)
df <- read.csv(paste(l[i]), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df.sep <- separate(data = df, col = MyColumn, into = c("start", "stop"), sep = "\\-")
```

This is where I don't know how to proceed.  I want to repeat the following steps for every row in the data.frame "df.sep" then go get the next csv file, repeat the first loop to generate a new "df.sep", then go through the steps below on each row of that data.frame.  Note that "nm" comes from the loop above and "n" is an existing list.

```
for(j in nrow(df.sep)){
new <- paste(nm, " ", df.sep[j,3], df.sep[j,6], sep="")
old <- paste("X", df.sep[j,8], sep="")
n[which(n == paste(old))] <- paste(new)
}
```

Essentially I need to use certain columns of multiple csv files to rename elements in a list.  How can I get these two loops to work together?  I can get the second part to replace a single value in n but not more than one at once.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output based on that

Comment: I recommend `purrr` for this sort of thing: https://serialmentor.com/blog/2016/6/13/reading-and-combining-many-tidy-data-files-in-R

Comment: There is no need for the second loop, R is a vector language; `new <- paste(nm, " ", df.sep[ ,3], df.sep[ ,6], sep=""); old <- paste("X", df.sep[ ,8], sep="")` will create the columns of results you'll need for assign statement.

Comment: Thanks, @Dave2e.  I was able to force my way through it using the vector approach combined with the accepted answer below.  I need to come back and review purrr that user Jon Spring recommended, too.  For the sake of time I got the work finished.  It might not be graceful, but it is done.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a skeleton code to read multiple csv files.
You can do the edit of df.sep.
I hope this helps.

```
# create a folder to save CSV files
myDirName = "folderCsv"
if(!dir.create(myDirName)){dir.create(myDirName)}

# loop to save files
set.seed(0)
maxNumFile = 2
for(ctFile in 1:maxNumFile){
  # create data
  numSample = 3
  df = data.frame(
    "col1" = paste0("X", floor(runif(n = numSample, min = 0, max = 10))),
    "col2" = floor(runif(n = numSample, min = 0, max = 10))
  )
  write.csv(x = df, file = paste0(myDirName, "/df", ctFile, ".csv"))
}

# prepare a list to save df.sep
lsdf.sep = vector(mode = "list", length = maxNumFile)

# open the CSV files
for(ctFile in 1:maxNumFile){ # Many R users prefer lapply to this For method.
  df.sep = read.csv(file = paste0(myDirName, "/df", ctFile, ".csv"), row.names = 1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  df.sep$col1[df.sep$col1 == "X8"] = "new8"
  lsdf.sep[[ctFile]] = df.sep
}

lsdf.sep
# [[1]]
# col1 col2
# 1 new8    5
# 2   X2    9
# 3   X3    2
# 
# [[2]]
# col1 col2
# 1 new8    6
# 2   X9    0
# 3   X6    2
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to work through it with your suggestion and Dave2e's comment.  I will revisit this in the future to make it more elegant, but for now it is done.

Comment: I meant 
if(!dir.exists(myDirName)){dir.create(myDirName)}
in the second line of the code.